# Multiple Versions of one single Cordova application with different names and bundle identifiers

Tags: android, ios, git, cordova, branding

I have a Cordova application that is supposed to be shipped to multiple customers.

So I have one master branch and a branch that can be branded for every customer.

My questions are now the following:

1. Which files do you exclude from `.git` (using the `.gitignore` file)?
2. How do you handle the installation process of cordova? Do you install cordova platforms and plugins in each and every customer branch?
3. We need different bundle identifiers and names for the app, this is especially a problem for the Xcode project because the name changes there.

Help and any shared ideas are really appreciated. 
Thanks!